# jquery getjson is not working when calling restful webservice

Tags: jquery, jsp, rest

I'm trying to call a restful webservice from my jsp page.

The restful web service is working fine and it is displaying the json data. The problem is with the client.
The client is not able to get the web service data.

I tried many ways but nothing worked.

This is the script:

```
function getEmployeeDetails() {
    alert("Hai");
    alert($("#empid").val());
    $empid = $("#empid");
    alert("eval-->" + $empid.val());
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/RestfulWS/restful/employee/" + $empid.val(), displayResult);

}

function displayResult(data) {
    alert("data" + data);

    $("#fname").val(data.firstName);
    $("#lname").val(data.lastName);
}​
```

and the HTML

```
<form id="form1">
    <h2>Employee Details</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee ID : </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="empid" size="10"/> <input type="button"  value="Get Details" onclick="getEmployeeDetails()" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FirstName : </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="fname" readonly size="30"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LastName :  </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="lname" readonly size="30"/></td>
        </tr>        
    </table>
</form>​
```

I am running the above code on tomcat with the port 19090.

Comment: i am running the above code on tomcat with the port 19090...

Comment: Your url should be : `http://localhost:19090/` ?

Comment: client code (jsp) is another web aplication which is running on tomcat 19090 and web service is running on tomcat 8080.

Comment: do you get any errors? What shows up in the alert box when `displayResult` is called?

Comment: Could you please post the controller code for `/restful/employee/` route?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{id}", 
     method = RequestMethod.GET, 
           headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
 public @ResponseBody Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
     logger.debug("Provider has received request to get employee with id: " + id);
     
     // Call service here
  return employeeService.get(id);
    }

Comment: The controller code is working fine.. it is displaying json data. in fire fox the client code shoing 200 OK.. but not anything

Comment: @MrOBrian..seems it is not reaching displayResult method.. i used firebug for debug there also it is showing 200 OK...

Comment: Ok, the problem is you are making cross domain requests. Allow cross domain requests in your controller.

Comment: could you please tell me how can i do that..please...atleast point me to the use links etc..if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Read [HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control), [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

and

[How the origin is being determined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules)

To configure your controller to allow cross domain requests,

[This link will help](http://thelab.athome-training.com/tutoriel/ajax-cross-domain-on-jersey-restfull-webservices)